# Why i am getting error: return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/SerDe

Tags: hadoop, hive

```
add jar /home/shashank/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin/lib/json-serde-1.3.7.3.jar;

create external table if not exists tweets ( text string,
entities STRUCT <
hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
`user` STRUCT<
screen_name:STRING,
friends_count:INT,
followers_count:INT,
statuses_count:INT,
verified:BOOLEAN,
utc_offset:INT,
time_zone:STRING>
)
row format SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
location '/user/hive/warehouse/twitter.db/tweets.json';
```

I am working on hive-2.3.2 and jar file path is added as i get the mssg from terminal,i tried different json-serde jar file but nothing work for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you include the whole stack?

Comment: thanks hlagos for the response please be more specific what you want me to do?

Comment: you should print all the error log/message